# Raspberry Pi 0 W SPI ioctl() call failure

Tags: pi-zero, spi, pi-3a+

I'm trying to setup my *Rasperry Pi 0* to use two *SPI* ports simultaneously I need such configuration since I need:

1. to connect this board trough *ETHERNET* to a local *LAN*;
2. to collect video stream from a camera (*FLIR Lepton 3*).

The first point is successfully achieved using an **ENC28J60** IC (it works fine).
The second point is a little more challenging because of several issues I run into, the first one seems to be related to *SPI* managing/setup but I'm not a deep expert of such protocol/standard and thus I'm looking for infos.
The camera is connected to `/dev/spidev1.1`:

My `config.txt` is set as follows:

```
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=enc28j60
dtoverlay=spi1-2cs
dtparam=audio=on
start_x=1
gpu_mem=128
```

I can shut off audio and maybe reduce the amount of GPU memory (the system will run on terminal only), but AFAIK it should be correct.

The core of my *solution* is a program written in C that should get data from the camera mentioned above trough *SPI* bus. Unluckly when the following code is executed:

```
spi_fd = open(device, O_RDWR);
{
    perror("can't open device");

    piUnlock(SPI_MUTEX);
    return  0;
}

_result = ioctl(spi_fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE, &mode);
if (_result == -1)
{
    perror("can't set spi mode");

    piUnlock(SPI_MUTEX);
    return 0;
}
```

The first `ioctl` call fails (return -1). 
What can it depend on?

To clearify where the problem is I can replace the camera with a micro programmed by myself and verify on the other side of *SPI* bus what's going on but first of all I need to know if the setup has a chance to work or not.

I did the same setup on a *Rasperry Pi 3 A+* with the same result.

I did some experiment connecting the camera on `/dev/spidev0.1` and in such case `ioctl()` call works unluckly I need to use *ENC28J60* to connect to LAN and I don't know a setup to use it trough a *different* SPI bus.

Comment: The camera output a video in 160x120@9Hz trough SPI (VO-SPI protocol).

Comment: Perhaps errno indicates the error?

Comment: good question. I'll check it.